# about initializing of viewcontroller (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, initialization

I have a ViewController file called `TwoViewController.swift` and a nib file called `TwoViewController.xib`.

`TwoViewController.swift` like this ↓

```
class TwoViewController: UIViewController {
    var pageTitle: String?

    ・・・・・・
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    ・・・・・・
}
```

then, I would new a TwoViewController and present it at `OneViewController.swift` like this↓

```
class OneViewController: UIViewController {

    ・・・・・・
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    ・・・・・・
    func presentTwo() {
       let two = new TwoViewController()
       two.pageTitle = "2222"
       self.present(two, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But, I want to `new TwoViewController` and set value to property `pageTitle` at the same time like this ↓
`new TwoViewController(pageTitle: "22222")`

To do that, I think I need create an init method at TwoViewController.
I tried to make an init method like below↓. Is this correct?

```
class TwoViewController: UIViewController {
    var pageTitle: String

    init(pageTitle: String) {
       super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
       self.pageTitle = pageTitle
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    ・・・・・・
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do so, but then you'd have to initialize `pageTitle` in every initializer with some default value, which you typically don't know.

Therefore, this is not quite common to do so. Instead assign the property value after initialization, like you did originally (in `funcTwo`), and go on with processing in `viewDidLoad`:

```
class TwoViewController: UIViewController {
    var pageTitle: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // use pageTitle to fill some outlet or so:
        self.title = pageTitle
    }
}
```

or make `pageTitle` an optional and check in `viewDidLoad` if it is set.

---

By the way: If you follow the naming scheme and name your XIB file like your view controller, you could use the implicit form:

```
let twoController = TwoViewController.init()
```

or explicitly

```
    let twoController = TwoViewController.init(nibName: "TwoViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should initialise your TwoViewController from your nib file like this :

```
let twoController = TwoViewController.init(nibName: "TwoViewController", bundle: nil)
```

then you can initialise your pageTitle like this :

```
twoController.pageTitle = "2222"
```

then you can present your twoViewController like this :

```
self.present(twoController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```